# How to move and/or rotate a semi circle or like any equation. Or just add a perimeter cut off on one of the sides.

Tags: graphing-functions, rotations, desmos

I'm just some random 6th grader having fun in graphing trying to get some practice in before high-school but my teacher says she doesn't know how to rotate any equation or how to rotate this semi circle graph https://www.desmos.com/calculator/u34ogdt5wd. I was wondering if there's possibly anyone that could help me because im trying to do the desmos marbleslide challenge #30 on Andymath.com and cant get the semi circles to move/rotate/or get a perimeter cut off on the side. Also how do you move any equation on a graph left to right or up and down without any changes to It's shape. Just wondering.

Comment: ..' Also how do you move any equation on a graph left to right or up and down without any changes to It's shape.'..I can be done by changing $x/y$ to $x+c/y+c$ ,where c specifies how many units you want to shift.Also this might help in rotation:https://www.desmos.com/calculator/n5zvasi8dy

Comment: In your particular form of the equation you can just replace $\{y<0\}$ with some other inequality such as $\{y<-(1/2)x\}$ or  $\{y>2x\}.$

Comment: From the terms of service for this website: "You must be at least 13 years old to access or use the Network or Services...."

Answer (score 1):

[You might want to look at this](https://vondesmos.wordpress.com/2016/01/28/rotating-a-function/#:%7E:text=Click%20on%20the%20image%20of,or%20goes%20back%20and%20forth.)

Basically, the idea is that a rotation of the graph is basically given by the following:

$$\begin{pmatrix}x_{new} \\\ y_{new} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}x \\\ y \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$

$(x_{new},y_{new})$ is the new coordinate after the rotation

$(x,y)$ is the old coordinate
$$\theta$$ is the angle of rotation.

The proof is a bit long but read up on it when you're free!